# How to resolve MISRA C:2012 Rule:8.4?

Tags: c, embedded, misra

I have a C code which I am trying to make it MISRA Compliance.I am getting following error in two different case:

Case 1]note 9075: external symbol 'buf' defined without a prior declaration [MISRA 2012 Rule 8.4, required] uint32_t buf[BUF_SIZE](in main.c);

How can I define it an another way so it will follow MISRA rule ?

Case 2] note 9075: external symbol 'buf' defined without a prior declaration [MISRA 2012 Rule 8.4, required] uint32_t buf[64U];

```
case1:
header.h
#define BUF_SIZE 64U
test.c
#include "header.h"
uint32_t buf[BUF_SIZE];

case2:
test.c
uint32_t buf[64U];
```

Comment: You should not be using SO as a MISRA C training course - you are posting many similar questions.

Comment: The note 9075 in case 1 refers to _main.c_ : you have posted code form test.c - we have to conclude that this is not the same code.  The second cse does not mention a source file at all.  Are you sure you have transcribed these reports verbatim?

Comment: Here I posted demo code for issue regarding to particular variable declaration and solution  given by John is working fine@Clifford

Comment: yes, but John had to provide two possible solutions because from the fragment, it was not possible to determine how you were using buf that would cause this error. We should not have to guess. Moreover my point stands, if you minimise the code, the error message should refer to that code, not to some other code. You need to demonstrate that the "demo" code reproduced the error, and that you have provided everything necessary to reproduce the error. This fragment alone would not do that. You have removed all necessary context. It is how you have used buf that causes this error, not this alone.

Comment: Ok  I got your point. @Clifford

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> How can I define it an another way so it will follow MISRA rule ?

**If the array is meant to be accessed by code from multiple different files**, then put a declaration of it into `header.h`:

```
extern uint32_t buf[BUF_SIZE];
```

Do not omit the `extern`.  Do not omit the array size, although standard C permits doing so.  Keep the definition already present in the .c file, unmodified.

**If the array is meant for use only in the file in which it is declared**, then make it static:

```
static uint32_t buf[BUF_SIZE];
```

*Do not* declare it in any header in this case.